# Initializing multiple classes with values from a JSON file seems to create duplicates

Tags: json, python-3.x, class

I have a main class called Dense that has many variables, and I have another class called Sequential that stacks these layers on-top of each other in an array, and allows easy communication between them.

At some point in my program I end up saving all the variables for each seperate Dense class in a JSON file for later use. It looks a little something like this:

```py
    {
     "layer: 0":{
         .
         .
         .
         variables
         .
         .
         .
     },

     "layer: 1":{
         .
         .
         .
         variables
         .
         .
         .
     }
    }
```

When I then take these dicts and load them back into my layers, when i'm using them later on, the values of the final layer in the Sequential class seem to copy themselves over to every other layer.

Here is the best I can do at recreating the code

```py
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
import os
import json

class Base_Layer(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self, name:str, **kwargs) -> None:
        self.name = name


    @abstractmethod
    def get_summary(self) -> dict:
        return summary


    @abstractmethod
    def load(self, layer_data:dict) -> None:
        pass





class Dense(Base_Layer):
    def __init__(self, layer_shape:tuple):
        super().__init__("Dense")

        self.layer_shape = layer_shape


    def get_summary(self):
        summary = {
                    "name":self.name,
                    "layer_shape":self.layer_shape
                  }
        return summary


    def load(self, layer_data):
        self.name = layer_data["name"]
        self.layer_shape = tuple(layer_data["layer_shape"])





class Sequential:
    def __init__(self, model=[]):
        self.model = model


    def save(self, file_path):

        summaries = []
        for layer in self.model:
            summaries.append(layer.get_summary())


        saved_model = {}
        for i in range(len(summaries)):
            saved_model["layer: %s" % i] = {}
            for key in summaries[i]:
                saved_model["layer: %s" % i][key] = summaries[i][key]

        with open(file_path, "w+") as json_file:
            json_file.write(json.dumps(saved_model, indent=2))


    def load(self, file_path):
        layers = {
                    "Dense":Dense((0, 0)),
                 }

        # Try to open the file at file_path.
        try:
            with open(file_path, "r") as json_file:
                model_layers = json.loads(json_file.read())

                for i in range(len(model_layers)):
                    layer_data = model_layers["layer: %s" % i]
                    self.model.append(layers[layer_data["name"]])
                    self.model[-1].load(layer_data)

        # Gets called if the program can't find the file_path.
        except Exception as e:
            raise FileNotFoundError("Can't find file path %s. Try saving the model or enter a correct file path." % file_path)



seq_model = Sequential([
                            Dense((128, 784)),
                            Dense((128, 128)),
                            Dense((128, 128)),
                            Dense((32, 128)),
                            Dense((10, 32)),
                      ])

file_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "/recreate_error_test.json"
seq_model.save(file_path)
seq_model.load(file_path)




for layer in seq_model.model:
    print(layer.layer_shape)
```

This actually outputs:
(128, 784)
(128, 128)
(128, 128)
(32, 128)
(10, 32)
(10, 32)
(10, 32)
(10, 32)
(10, 32)
(10, 32)

Which is strange as to why it's printing twice, the first 7 values are correct, and the next 7 show the problem I am facing in my actual code.

Any help with this problem would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: "layer: 0"{...}  is not valid json content, "layer: 0":{...} would be more correct.

Comment: @philippelhardy thanks, I just edited the question to add your changes.

Comment: self.model.append(layers[layer_data["name"]])
self.model[-1].load(layer_data) <=?=>
self.model.append(layers[layer_data["name"]].load(layer_data)

Comment: @philippelhardy Does that fix the problem or is it just a better way to write the code?

Comment: self.model.append(layers[layer_data["name"]]) self.model[-1].load(layer_data) ~= self.model.append(layers["Dense"].load(layer_data))  ==> layers["Dense"] is then the object that is appended to the list, this is the very same object. by chance append might clone it but i think it is not cloned always so has side effects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is reuse of layers[layer_data["name"]] , this is the same reference that is added to the list. Dense.load() does not recreate a new Dense object it fills it.

Here some rewrite on load function to see the element creation.

```
import copy

(...)



    def load(self, file_path):
        layers = {
                    "Dense":Dense((0, 0)),
                 }

        # Try to open the file at file_path.
        try:
            with open(file_path, "r") as json_file:
                model_layers = json.loads(json_file.read())

                for i in range(len(model_layers)):
                    layer_data = model_layers["layer: %s" % i]
                    print("%s %s" %( i,layer_data["name"]))
                    # OK could be new_layer=Dense((0, 0)) since it recreate a new object
                    new_layer=copy.copy(layers[layer_data["name"]])
                    # NOK same reference is reused
                    # new_layer=layers[layer_data["name"]]
                    new_layer.load(layer_data)
                    self.model.append(new_layer)

        # Gets called if the program can't find the file_path.
        except Exception as e:
            raise FileNotFoundError("Can't find file path %s. Try saving the model or enter a correct file path." % file_path)
```

Here another solution using class name without need of copy :

```
def load(self, file_path):
    layerclass = {
                "Dense":Dense,
             }

    # Try to open the file at file_path.
    try:
        with open(file_path, "r") as json_file:
            model_layers = json.loads(json_file.read())

            for i in range(len(model_layers)):
                layer_data = model_layers["layer: %s" % i]
                print("%s %s" %( i,layer_data["name"]))
                # requires that all layerclass have a __init__ constructor with layer_shape tuple.
                new_layer=layerclass[layer_data["name"]](layer_shape=(0,0))
                new_layer.load(layer_data)
                self.model.append(new_layer)

    # Gets called if the program can't find the file_path.
    except Exception as e:
        raise FileNotFoundError("Can't find file path %s. Try saving the model or enter a correct file path." % file_path)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the code works. However, I unfortunately don't understand how this fixes the problem so I guess i'll have to do some research on the python copy library.

Comment: well, your first probelm is that you save() and load() on the same model list, so the first 5 ( and not 7 ) are just your input, the 5 next are the result of load. then all the 5 loaded value just  point to the very same object. No need of copy, just create correct class instance is enough